# Does Access 2007 return NULL on character fields when using SendObject?

Tags: excel, ms-access-2007, reporting

I send out reports via email using, among other things, SendObject in Access 2007 (to Excel 2007 workbooks). I noticed yesterday when attempting to show someone how to do a pivot table on an emailed report that fields that should be blank in Excel (NULL in Access) are being counted as having a value in them by the pivot table. Doing COUNTA in Excel on the column shows that Excel thinks there are values in the cells that should be blank (NULL). (When I run the same query in SSMS, I get NULL and a pivot table using this data works as expected). Columns in the SendObject workbook/worksheet that contain a mix of date values or numbers work as expected -- fields with values are counted and fields without values are not. So has Access always returned non-blank (non-NULL) values if the field is a character field and I just haven't noticed until now?

Comment: I find that the cells are not blank, but seem to contain a zero-length string, so I guess that it is standard.

Comment: I recently had a similar scenario and after investigation came to the same conclusion as @Remou. For my purposes, the data had already been imported from Excel to Access so I ran an update query to swap my zero-length string ("") values to null strings in Access.

Comment: Oh I neglected to mention this this is on pass-through queries directly to SQL Server (if that matters). But I'm getting the feeling that this might be the standard. I was going to look into creating the reports using TransferSpreadsheet anyway (for more functionality, customization) so this is not that big of an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this and it does indeed seem to be the case that NULL fields are transferred to Excel as non-NULL empty sets (which, when put in a pivot table and counted are counted as having a value). I ended-up changing the system to use the TransferSpreadsheet method which fixed this issue and allows us a lot more functionality and customization. Thanks!